# Getting null as result from JQ command only when using variable

Tags: bash, shell-script, jq

I am trying to use `jq` to parse some JSON to allow me to get values out of a json file. The setup is I have a JSON file that if I run my `jq` command against with my manually entering the key it will work. However when I try using either `--args` or env it fails with `null` as the result.

Code

```
stripped_string=$(echo $key | tr -d '"' | tr -d ',')
jq -r --arg str "${stripped_string}" '.data."$str"' 1password.json
```

I have confirmed with `echo` that I am getting the correct value for `stripped_string` and if I replace `$str` with a key it will work perfectly fine.

How can I get this `jq` command to work with `stripped_string` as the key it returns the value for?

Edit adding info

example `$key`
"JON_CONSUMER_KEY"

shortened 1password.json

```
"data": {
        "JON_CONSUMER_KEY": "<value here>",
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Starting by assuming the data is valid JSON, such as

```json
{
   "data": { "JON_CONSUMER_KEY": "<value here>" }
}
```

... where `data` is a top-level key, we may get the decoded (raw) value of the `JON_CONSUMER_KEY` key under `data` using a user-supplied string like so:

```bash
$ mykey=JON_CONSUMER_KEY
$ jq -r --arg key "$mykey" '.data[$key]' file
<value here>
```

Note the syntax for extracting the value of the key under `data`.

Using `.data."$key"` would work if the key was *literally* `$key`.  If there is no such key, you would naturally get `null` back.